# How to check if a text field is not null, not empty, doesn't contain white space in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, text

How to check if a text field is not null, not empty, doesn't contain white space in SOQL? Other than using something like,

```
AND (field__c != null AND field__c != '' AND Field__c != ' ')
```

in the WHERE clause of my SOQL, which isn't taking all the situations into account, how can I do this? I'm looking at the string class method such as,

```
String.isNotBlank()
```

I know I can iterate over the result of the query and filter out what I don't need but I'm asking this question to avoid that if possible to implement something within the query itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOQL cannot do this directly, it has no `ISEMPTY()` function. Even if it did, using negative filters has implications with query selectivity.

The best approach here, if you want to avoid doing the work in Apex, would be to create a formula field (boolean/checkbox) that tells you whether or not a field is blank, and then including that in your query (either `WHERE Formula_Field__c = true` or `WHERE Formula_Field__c = false`)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it can't be done through SOQL. I really like your suggestion as well. Which is the best way to do this though in terms of performance and best practices?

Comment: @Bahman.A I doubt you'd be able to tell a difference in terms of performance (also, microoptimization is bad). As for best practice, I don't think that's really established here. There are arguments that could be made for both approaches (apex / formula field).

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, Salesforce doesn't store empty strings (i.e. `''`) in sobject records, it just gets treated as null.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is all great information.

Comment: The `isBlank()` will catch null, `''` (empty string, only an issue for records created/altered in memory), and `' '` (string with one blank space). My point was that `''` and null are basically equivalent when you're writing a query.

Comment: Yah, thanks for clearing that up, I confused empty strings with strings that contain white space when I read your comment. So I still need to have a way to check those if they're saved with white spaces (one or more).

Comment: @DerekF without knowing the OPs exact SOQL in terms of understanding or not if `field__c != null` is a field on a related object, do you see any concerns knowing formula fields are categorized as non-selective?

Comment: @DerekF This is really helpful, is there also some official documentation for this statement? _"Salesforce doesn't store empty strings (i.e. '') in sobject records, it just gets treated as null"_

Comment: @Bloke Nothing official that I'm aware of. It's just a general observation that I and several others have made. It might be a result of some quirk in Oracle's RDBMS (which Salesforce uses).